# Using Typescript Compiler API to rewrite typescript file

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm  trying to work with Typescript Compiler API to create a tool for merging typescript files. I'd like to know is there a way to:

1. Change AST after it was produced by parsing .ts file.
2. Serialize changed AST back to .ts file

I have read [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) on Compiler API, but it seems to cover only read-only uses-cases of working with AST, while I'm more interesting in modifying source files.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You want to modify them in place?

Comment: This is not very important - in place or create another tree and write it. I prefer to work at AST level hovewer, but right now i'm researching a solution based on working with text, inserting it at the locations computed from AST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Change AST after it was produced by parsing .ts file.
>   Serialize changed AST back to .ts file

Both of these are emitter plugins, you need to add a custom `transformer`. The best docs are still in the PR https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13940